# Is $\{(\omega, x) \in \Omega \times \mathbb{R}: X(\omega) > x\}$ measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Here $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ is the sample space, $X$ is a real-valued random variable, and in its codomain I am considering $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ as the $\sigma$-field. I am asking if the set is measurable in the product space of $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ and $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.

The motivation of this question is in the proof that for a nonnegative random variable $X$, $EX = \int_{[0,+\infty)}P(X > x)dx$. To prove this result, we need Fubini theorem, and the condition of the theorem reduces to a positive answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\{(\omega, x) \in \Omega \times \mathbb{R}: X(\omega) > x\}=\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb Q} [X^{-1}(q,\infty)\times (-\infty,q )]$.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I will explore it in detail later.